# Position labels inside circuitikz reisistors

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, labels, circuitikz

I'm trying to position the labels for (european) resistors in circuitikz inside the resistors,
[image: What I want]
but it automatically positions them besides the boxes and I get this:

[image: What I get:]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[scale = 0.5,european]
            % start points
            \coordinate[label=above:B] (B) at (0,0);
            \coordinate[label=above:A] (A) at (0,5);
            \foreach \i in {A,B} {
                \fill (\i) circle (2pt);
            }
            \draw (B) to (4,0) to (4,-1) to[R, label={$2R$}] (8,-1) to (8,0);
            \draw (4,0) to (4,1) to[R, label={$2R$}] (8,1) to (8,0) to (12,0) to[R, l_={$R$}] (12,5) to[] (11,5);
            \draw (A) to[] (1,5) to (1,3) to[R, label={$2R$}] (11,3) to[] (11,5);
            \draw (1,5) to[R, label={$R$}] (6,5) to[R, label={$R$}] (11,5);
        \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, this is not really supported. It would be wrong with most of the components, and the idea of `circuitikz` is that you can switch from `european` to `american` and still have a valid circuit...

But you can trick it into working:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[scale = 0.5,european]
            % start points
            \coordinate[label=above:B] (B) at (0,0);
            \coordinate[label=above:A] (A) at (0,5);
            \foreach \i in {A,B} {
                \fill (\i) circle (2pt);
            }
            % name the node, and...
            \draw (B) to (4,0) to (4,-1) to[R, name=R1] (8,-1) to (8,0);
            % add the thing
            \node  at (R1.center) {$R$};
            \draw (4,0) to (4,1) to[R, label={$2R$}] (8,1) to (8,0) to (12,0) to[R, l_={$R$}] (12,5) to[] (11,5);
            \draw (A) to[] (1,5) to (1,3) to[R, label={$2R$}] (11,3) to[] (11,5);
            \draw (1,5) to[R, label={$R$}] (6,5) to[R, label={$R$}] (11,5);
        \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also automate them, using a consistent naming scheme:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale = 0.5,european]
            % start points
            \coordinate[label=above:B] (B) at (0,0);
            \coordinate[label=above:A] (A) at (0,5);
            \foreach \i in {A,B} {
                \fill (\i) circle (2pt);
            }
            % name the nodes Rx for R and 2Rx for 2R, and...
            \draw (B) to (4,0) to (4,-1) to[R, name=R1] (8,-1) to (8,0);
            \draw (4,0) to (4,1) to[R, name=2R1] (8,1) to (8,0) to (12,0) to[R, name=R2] (12,5) to[] (11,5);
            \draw (A) to[] (1,5) to (1,3) to[R, name=2R2] (11,3) to[] (11,5);
            \draw (1,5) to[R, name=R3] (6,5) to[R, name=R4] (11,5);
            % add labels
            \foreach \n in {1,...,4} \node at (R\n.center) {$R$};
            \foreach \n in {1,2} \node at (2R\n.center) {$2R$};
        \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]